# Selenium IDE : Not able to perform operation on new tab

Tags: selenium-ide

i am not able to perform operation on new tab.Consider the following scenario :
Add a ticket,after adding ticket, page goes to view tickets page ( all the actions are performed on same tab) 
            On this page,i got three options View,Edit and delete tickets.
           If i click on View or edit icon the new tab is get opened.

Everything are performed till above but after opening new tab,selenium ide doesn't recognise or not able to perform operations on newly opened tab.

(**note** :- we are stick to selenium ide 1.10.0 )

Answer (score 0):

use waitForVisible on one of the elements on the tab.

Also try slowing down the execution with the speed slider to see if this helps.

Comment: Hi Chim, Thanks for the answer,but it won't work for my application ( may be their is no such a field which suitable for waitForVisible command ). Getting same error or output after implementing that command.:(

Comment: How did slowing down the execution speed go?